# java struts global exception handling

Tags: java, exception, struts2

I am trying to implement global exception handling in a struts.xml file. My struts.xml file is set up like this:

```
<struts>
      <constant ..... />
           <include ......./>
</struts>
```

How should I nest the global exception mapping and global results elements in this file?

Comment: this is not really a question, what is your problem?

Comment: By following the [S2 configuration DTD](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.3/docs/strutsxml-examples.html) and every example out there.

Answer (score 1):

In the [S2](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.3/docs/exception-handling.html) docs it's the answer:

```
<global-exception-mappings>
    <exception-mapping exception="org.apache.struts.register.exceptions.SecurityBreachException" result="securityerror" />
       <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="error" />
</global-exception-mappings>

<global-results>
        <result name="securityerror">/securityerror.jsp</result>
         <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</global-results>
```